# Python Binary Search Mid calculation

Tags: python, binary-search

**Why " *mid = (high + low) // 2* " instead of " *mid = high//2* " ?**
I can't fully understand why they use **mid = (high + low)//2** If anybody can demystify my understanding of this, that would be greatly appreciated  :)

```
# Iterative Binary Search Function
# It returns index of x in given array arr if present,
# else returns -1
def binary_search(arr, x):
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0

    while low <= high:

        mid = (high + low) // 2

        # If x is greater, ignore left half
        if arr[mid] < x:
            low = mid + 1

        # If x is smaller, ignore right half
        elif arr[mid] > x:
            high = mid - 1

        # means x is present at mid
        else:
            return mid

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present
    return -1


# Test array
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ]
x = 10

# Function call
result = binary_search(arr, x)

if result != -1:
    print("Element is present at index", str(result))
else:
    print("Element is not present in array")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because both `low` and `high` are moving when your algorithm plays out. `mid` is not the strict middle of the array, it's the middle of the *rest of the values* you have to search through: the middle between `low` and `high`. Thus we compute the average: **(low+high) // 2**  to get `mid`.

To better visualize the problem:
[image: Binary Search Gif]

Answer (score 0):

`(high + low) // 2` ensures the `mid` index is within the range of `low` and `high`. If you don't use `low` in your `mid` calculation, you could end up with a result where `mid < low`, which breaks the binary search because you stop searching within the range of values you've already narrowed it down to.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to search in `[5, 4, 7, 8, 1, 2, 11, 12]`
indices will be: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

For binary search, we have to divide it in half.

middle element : `mid = (high + low )/ 2`

here `high = 7` and `low = 0`, hence you might be thinking why do we even need to use low when it is zero.

But when we have to divide the second half of the array further, i.e. `[1, 2, 11, 12]` with indices `[4, 5, 6, 7]`

`mid = (high + low) / 2`
`high = 7, low = 4`, hence `mid = 6`. Here you cannot do `mid = high/2`. You can see the difference. It helps to get to the right middle place for all the halves.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[2, 3, 4, 10, 40]
```

while doing binary search on this array for 10
watch closely at the value of high,low and mid you will get it why do we use it

```
high = 4
low  = 0 
mid = 2
```

now as the value on mid  is less than 10 we will change the mid with low

```
low = 2
high = 4
mid = 3
```

hence found the number

as you can see why we put low to calculate the mid value if we do not do this mid will all the time come 2 for this case and we will not be able to traverse in the array .